# Unable to add certificate to LinkedIn Profile via LinkedIn API if LinkedIn app installed on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, linkedin-api

== Problem Summary ==

The problem is that opening a URL from my iOS App which adds a certificate to a user's LinkedIn profile redirects to the LinkedIn app (if installed). The LinkedIn app doesn't seem to handle this URL correctly (or I need a different URL) so I'm unable to link certificates to profile if a LinkedIn app is installed on an iOS device.

'Docs' for adding a certificate:
https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/cert

== Details ==

Using the LinkedIn API I'm successfully able to link a certificate to a profile using a URL like so:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add
    ?_ed=<value>
    &pfCertificationName=<name>
    &pfCertificationUrl=<url>
    &source=o
    &pfLicenseNo=<licenseNo>
    &pfCertStartDate=201510
    &trk=<value>
```

This works on other platforms like desktop web and android just fine. From within our iOS mobile app I'm able to execute this url via the app delegate:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

...to have the url open in mobile safari and successfully provide UI to add the certificate to the user's LinkedIn profile (in mobile safari).

== LinkedIn App issues ==

However, if the LinkedIn app is installed on device then the url re-directs from mobile safari into the LinkedIn app and does not provide UI to add the certificate to the user's LinkedIn profile. Actually I'm brought to a page in the LinkedIn app which reads 'This profile is not available'.

I tried integrating the LinkedIn SDK to see if that would help, however, it just opens the LinkedIn app to the launch page and provides no further UI to link the certification. I've tried both post and get requests with the URL. Here is some Swift code I've used:

```
let url: NSURL = <url_i_mention_above>

let linkToProfile: Void -> Void = {
    LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest(
        url.absoluteString,
        stringBody: "",
        success: { (response) in
            logError("LinkedIn Response: \(response.data)")
        },

        error: { (error) in
            logError("LinkedIn Error: \(error)")
    })
}

if !LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession() {
    LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth([LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION], state: "", showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) in
        logError("LinkedIn Auth Success: \(returnState)")
        linkToProfile()
        }, errorBlock: { (error) in
            logError("LinkedIn Auth Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    })
} else {
    linkToProfile()
}
```

LinkedIn documentation doesn't really exist on the certificate adding feature outside of a web button. 
Docs: https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/cert

Also, LinkedIn doesn't offer support outside of StackOverflow: 
https://developer.linkedin.com/support

These are the questions I have that I could use help answering:

- Has anyone successfully added a certificate to a LinkedIn profile on
  iOS through the app?
- Can anyone spot anything wrong with my URL or request?
- Does LinkedIn even support adding a certificate to the profile through their app?

Any help would be awesome. I have not found answers within the small amount of LinkedIn mobile SDK documentation here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk

For reference, this is the section on authentication for the code above:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk-auth